# How to stop utility "main" from interfering with real "main" SpringBoot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot app that has been working fine:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class }, 
    scanBasePackageClasses = { IndexSyncController.class, IndexerService.class })
@ImportResource("classpath:/spring.xml")
public class AppLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppLauncher.class, args);
    }
```

And also currently sitting in `src/test/java`, I have a "utility" which has its own main method. This too has been working fine, but can only launched in my development environment:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
public class AuditApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppLauncher.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        return args -> {
            ...
        };
    }
```

Now I have a new requirement

> I need to take the `AuditApp` utility from `src/test/java` and make it available in the production jar.

So I just move it from `src/test/java` to `src/main/java` right? Nope! Very first obstacle I ran into when I do that, is that the main application tries to run the `commandLineRunner()`. Because of past experience with a similar requirement, I believe this is just the tip of the iceberg and there will be additional issues.

Is there a canonical, general best-practice or checklist for how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to consider is the real reason of your problem.
You missed out packages of mentioned classes, but looking at your symptoms, I suspect your `AuditApp` is in the same package, or in a subpackage of one the `AppLauncher` is in (or is in package scanned by config declared inside imported spring.xml).

The `@SpringBootApplication` is an abbreviation for (amongst [other](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html)) `@SpringBootConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`.
Because of this the `AppLauncher` treats `AuditApp` as a `@SpringBootConfiguration` on a package scan and instantiates beans created within this config. The `AuditApp.main` method is never called, but the beans declared in the config are instantianted.

Let's say you have `AppLauncher` in `com.yourapp` and `AuditApp` in `com.yourapp.audit`.
If you move your utility application to the package which is not under the package scan for `AppLauncher`, like `com.yourauditapp`. The `CommandLineRunner` bean won't be created when running the original application. And the `AuditApp` won't affect the original application.

The only other way it can interfere is when it introduces dependencies which may trigger some Spring-Boot autoconfigurations.